# How to read google sheets from google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to read google sheet from google app engine using gspread-pandas package. In local machine, we usually store google_secret.json in specific path. But when it comes to app engine, I saved the file in /root/.config/gspread-pandas/google_secret.json but even then I am getting the same error as below

```
Please download json from https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials and save as /root/.config/gspread_pandas/google_secret.json
```

2) To add to this, I have created credentials part from the GCS and now trying to get the dict file in Spread class of gspread pandas. But, since we need to store the authorization code the first time, the app engine access, the failure is still happening for google app engine

Thank you in advance

Comment: never used the python version of app engine, but I'm pretty sure you can't save file in a persistent way on the machine unless you are packaging the file with your code. Why don't you use the default service account credentials to download the google_secret.json file from gcs ? (or use the default credentials directly)

Comment: Hi Plevis.. because the gspread pandas is designed to fetch the credential from the specified directory. If the file is  not stored in persistent way, then I think I may have to opt for other method. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I have tried using service account key and all other keys as well. But the result is still the same. Tried to change the config file as well. But the file that is stored inside is not being considered for reading sheets

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve your technical purpose - doing operations with Google Sheets from App Engine, I would recommend you to use the Google Sheets API [1](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/). This API let's you read and write data, format text and numbers, create charts and many other features.

Here [2](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) there is a quickstart for Python, for this API. If you stil encounter compatibility issues, or you have a hard time getting/ storing the credentials in a persistent way, you can always opt for App Engine Flexible, which offers you more freedom [3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/).